# Grabbing song info from MPMediaItemPicker

Tags: ios, swift, media

I am attempting to assign the song title, author, and seconds played of a song to a set of variables.  However I am unable to pull any information from the song, what would be the best way to do this as currently my way crashes.

```
func presentPicker (sender:AnyObject) {
//I have all of this within an IBAction if that matters, I am new to programming in general so sorry if theres any stupid mistakes
    let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Music)
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    presentViewController(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: {println(MPMediaItemCollection())})

}
```

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: which method, and I believe the crash is because completion simply means when the view controller is presented, which would be before a song has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the `completion` argument of `presentViewController:`. The completion runs when the controller successfully presents, but you want to grab the song when it's finished dismissing. You need to implement this delegate method in your class:

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!,
    didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {
    println(mediaItemCollection)
}
```

That method will be called on your class when the user has selected a song because you set `delegate` equal to `self`. You may also want to implement this one to find out if they cancelled the picker:

```
func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused what I would put in the Underscores in that situation

Comment: You don't need to include the underscore in your code. I updated my answer to show an example method.

Comment: For some reason this isnt printing out any results

Comment: Please update the code in your question to include the full class.